# Why is a new syntax required for member initalization in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose I have a class `C` with two private members: `a`, and `b` that have one parameter each. Why is the following syntax required to initialize my two members?

```
C() : a(x), b(y) {}
```

If I were initializing two objects anywhere else, the syntax would be simply:

```
A a = A(x);
B b = B(y);
```

where `A` and `B` are the types (and constructors) of `a` and `b`, respectively, and `x`, `y` represent an arbitrary argument of the same type the `A` and `B` constructors expect.

So, why does this syntax not work, requiring the use of a member initialization list, as in the example above?

```
C() {
    A a = A(x);
    B b = B(y);
}
```

The member initialization syntax is more concise, but I don't see why it is required. The above gives an error in g++ similar to:

```
note: candidate expects one argument, zero provided
```

for both `A` and `B`'s constructor.

The use of member initialization lists is not, for example, required (or possible, I believe) in Python. What was the motivation behind requiring this syntax in C++?

Comment: If an object requires some argument you have to provide one, the compiler does not play lottery (Member initialization is finished before the constructor body {}). In addition, prefer and get used to member initialization.

Comment: On top of that, you are not "initializing" member variables, but local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your confusion is that this syntax seems "unique" because you don't use it elsewhere.  That doesn't mean it isn't valid elsewhere.  This is correct *direct-initialization* of a local variable:

```
A a(x);
B b(y);
```

You've been doing *copy-initialization* this whole time.

The ctor-initializer list requires direct initialization, copy initialization is not allowed.  But it is not a *new syntax*.  It's what you should generally be using for local variables also.

Answer (score 1):

When the body of the constructor is executed, all member objects of the class have to be already initialized; if no initializer list is provided, the default constructor is called for every member object.

If there's no default constructor, then that error is triggered. So your choices are either to provide a default constructor for `A` and `B` or to use an initialization list.

This error can also be triggered in cases where you have a reference as a member object.